# Firefox marker-line like extension?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, vimperator, firefox-extensions, scrolling

Is there any marker-line like firefox extension? I would like some way to mark where I was before I scrolled so I don't need to remember exactly where I was before scrolling.

I also use Vimperator, so if there's any solution related to Vimperator that's good. I suppose some people get around this by using smooth-scrolling but I personally don't like that and prefer scrolling by page or half page.

Edit: I am not talking about highlighting text on web-pages.

Here's the pidgin markerline plugin description: "Draw a line to indicate new messages in a conversation."

Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image: Markerline example picture]

In this case all the text below the red line would be stuff that was not visible before I hit page-down in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Vimperator does provide local marks (towards the bottom of `:tab help marks`) that will save your scrolling position in the current tab. It doesn't provide a marker line, but that does sound like a useful plugin script or [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/entry?template=Vimperator%20feature%20request).

Comment: Thanks, I already do use Vimperator. However, the feature seems broken in my Vimp 3.8.1 on Firefox 25.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an extension to do that, but there is a Greasemonkey script that emulates it:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/38805

It's a bit flaky but it works. For me it goes on page-down, and seems to disappear as soon as I move the mouse.